# I have a react 4 router issue where url elements are not being properly debugged for conditional 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Thank you in advance for your assistance.  StackEx is simply amazing.

I have taken days to hunt and code and test,
and this first of two related blockers is the smaller one.

There is a failed react test which is most pressing:

- /hello/conehead => Responds correctly with "Hello conehead."  SUCCESS :)
- ** 404 page redirects work fine as a general rule,
  but the next item is an exception to that good rule..**
- /hello/cone/head? => Fails as desired, but does NOT redirect to 404 page. :(

Since I am using react router 4 ...... ,
I believe that I need to extract location params, but that is clearly failing.

Then I could also improve my conditional logic which drives redirect to 404.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location

The winner first clue would be to show me how to simply
properly console.log the router.location elements (!!!!)
*/

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Match } from "react-router-dom";

export default ({ match: { params: { name }}}) => { 
console.log(name); //  debug router match or location params ??
if (name.indexOf("/") > -1)
{ return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/404" }} />; } else 
{return (<h2>Hello {name}</h2>);
}}
```

[GIST WITH FULL DETAILS](https://gist.github.com/jeremy-donson/d9eae766cd90591015e1955d1162e30c)

Comment: Have you tried putting `debugger;` in the line with `console.log(name);` and opening DevTools ?

Comment: thx, zmil. Nope - doing that now.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript

Comment: Dev tools was open and console.log(name);
was showing only single parameter.

Still unclear about how to debug router 4 location object.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/location-object

console.log(location); dies

Goal: redirect  /helllo/second/third  or /name/second/third/fourth
to route /404. 

Does /hello/:name pass the above set of 2+ params?
because I am looking to redirect that to /404 route.

Ought this be debugged in App.js  else child component Routes.js
instead of in child component Namer.js ?

And how to dump all vars, funcs, objects, arrays?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/ see step 5 and 6.